# Target [App\Repositories\Setting\SettingRepositoryContract] is not instantiable while building [App\Http\Controllers\SettingsController]

Tags: laravel-5, controller

How can i solve Target [App\Repositories\Setting\SettingRepositoryContract] is not instantiable while building [App\Http\Controllers\SettingsController].

**Here is my controller**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Auth;
use Session;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Repositories\Setting\SettingRepositoryContract;
class SettingsController extends Controller
{
protected $settings;
public function __construct(
        SettingRepositoryContract $settings
    )
    {
        $this->settings = $settings;

    }
```

**SettingRepositoryContract**

```
namespace App\Repositories\Setting;

interface SettingRepositoryContract
{
    public function getCompanyName();

    public function updateOverall($requestData);

    public function getSetting();
}
```

NOTE: I am new to laravel and can't understand this error. So please help me if anyone know the answer.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do it right way:

SettingsRepositoryInterface

```
namespace App\Repositories;

interface SettingsRepositoryInterface
{
    public function getCompanyName();

    public function updateOverall($requestData);

    public function getSetting();
}
```

Implement the interface SettingsRepository

```
namespace App\Repositories;

use App\Repositories\SettingsRepositoryInterface;

class SettingsRepository implements SettingsRepositoryInterface
{
    public function getCompanyName()
    {
        // your code here
    }

    // all other functions here
}
```

Create a new service provider SettingsRepositoryServiceProvider

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class SettingsRepositoryServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(
        'App\Repositories\SettingsRepositoryInterface',
        'App\Repositories\SettingsRepository');
    }
}
```

Register your service provider by adding it to `config/app.php`

`App\Providers\SettingsRepositoryServiceProvider::class,`

And finally in your controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Auth;
use Session;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Repositories\SettingsRepositoryInterface;

class SettingsController extends Controller
{
    protected $settings;

    public function __construct(SettingsRepositoryInterface $settings)
    {
        $this->settings = $settings;
    }
 }
```

For your reference:

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/container & 
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/providers

Modify namespace according to your needs.